# Add custom TinyMCE 4 Button, Usable since WordPress 3.9-beta1

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce, visual-editor

How is it possible to add a custom button to the visual editor TinyMCE, **Version 4**?

Currently I found [this q&a](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138167/how-to-use-the-new-dashicons-for-custom-tinymce-buttons) with a little bit hints to the topic, but not a solution or a how to. But I can't find a tutorial, documentation, q&a for the topic to add a custom button to the TinyMCE version 4, include in WordPress since version 3.9-beta1.

#### Goal

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following small plugin creates a custom button inside line 1 of the WordPress TinyMCE Version 4, tested in WP Version 3.9-beta2.

The plugin has `var_dump` included to understand the values. It's also possible to add the button to other lines of the visual editor, only a other hook, like for line 2: `mce_buttons_2`.

#### Result

[image]

#### Plugin, PHP side - `tinymce4-test.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: TinyMCE 4 @ WP Test
 * Description: 
 * Plugin URI:  
 * Version:     0.0.1
 * Author:      Frank Bültge
 * Author URI:  http://bueltge.de
 * License:     GPLv2
 * License URI: ./assets/license.txt
 * Text Domain: 
 * Domain Path: /languages
 * Network:     false
 */

add_action( 'admin_head', 'fb_add_tinymce' );
function fb_add_tinymce() {
    global $typenow;

    // Only on Post Type: post and page
    if( ! in_array( $typenow, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) )
        return ;

    add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'fb_add_tinymce_plugin' );
    // Add to line 1 form WP TinyMCE
    add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'fb_add_tinymce_button' );
}

// Inlcude the JS for TinyMCE
function fb_add_tinymce_plugin( $plugin_array ) {

    $plugin_array['fb_test'] = plugins_url( '/plugin.js', __FILE__ );
    // Print all plugin JS path
    var_dump( $plugin_array );
    return $plugin_array;
}

// Add the button key for address via JS
function fb_add_tinymce_button( $buttons ) {

    array_push( $buttons, 'fb_test_button_key' );
    // Print all buttons
    var_dump( $buttons );
    return $buttons;
}
```

#### Script, JavaScript side - `plugin.js`

```
( function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'fb_test', function( editor, url ) {

        // Add a button that opens a window
        editor.addButton( 'fb_test_button_key', {

            text: 'FB Test Button',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function() {
                // Open window
                editor.windowManager.open( {
                    title: 'Example plugin',
                    body: [{
                        type: 'textbox',
                        name: 'title',
                        label: 'Title'
                    }],
                    onsubmit: function( e ) {
                        // Insert content when the window form is submitted
                        editor.insertContent( 'Title: ' + e.data.title );
                    }

                } );
            }

        } );

    } );

} )();
```

#### Gist

Use the [Gist bueltge/9758082](https://gist.github.com/bueltge/9758082) as reference, or download. The Gist also has more examples for different buttons in TinyMCE.

#### Links

- [TinyMCE API 4](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:index)
- [Migration guide from 3.x](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x)
- [WP Trac Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24067)
- [TinyMCE Default Font for Icons-Fonts](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts)
- [Alternative Icon via Dashicon or Genericons](https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style)
- [TinyMCE Default Plugins](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/tree/master/js/tinymce/plugins)
- [Compat Plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:compat3x) - This plugin contains a few compatibility files for the old 3.x branch. This enables you to run most old 3.x plugins with out any modifications.

Comment: The TinyMCE documentation on how to create dialog isn't actually very helpful. So I went ahead and wrote an article listing the different widgets and containers layout available: http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2016/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-in-tinymce-4

Answer (score 3):

And, if you'd like to have an actual icon button, then you can leverage dashicons, or your own icon font for it.

Create a CSS file, and enqueue on the admin side;

```
i.mce-i-pluginname:before {
    content: "\f164";
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-align: center;
    font: 400 20px/1 dashicons!important;
    speak: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Basically taken straight from core.

Comment: Right, was inside my Links above in the Links-list.

Comment: Wish I had found this answer before spending half an hour trying to add it via a CSS file. This seems like the best way to do it; all the tutorials I've found online are unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 0):

The simple method of adding button

**1)  ADD THIS CODE INTO FUNCTIONS.PHP, OR IN PLUGIN**

```
//add_protect_shortcode_button
add_action('admin_init', 'add_cb_button');function add_cb_button() {
   if (current_user_can('edit_posts')  &&  get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
        add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'register_buttonfirst');
        add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'add_pluginfirst');
   }
}
function register_buttonfirst($buttons) {  array_push($buttons, "|", "shortcode_button1" );   return $buttons;}
function add_pluginfirst($plugin_array) {$plugin_array['MyPuginButtonTag'] =  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'My_js_folder/1_button.php';return $plugin_array;}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_version', 'my_refresh_mceeee1');  function my_refresh_mceeee1($ver) {$ver += 3;return $ver;}
```

**2) Create 1_button.php in target folder and insert this code   (note, change "wp-load" and "ButtonImage.png" urls!!!)**

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");
require('../../../../wp-load.php');
?>
(function() {
    // START my customs
    var abcd =location.host;

    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.shortcodebuton_plugin2', {  
        init            : function(ed, this_folder_url)
        {
                    // -------------------------
                    ed.addButton('shortcode_button1', {  
                        title : 'Show Level1 count',  
                        image : this_folder_url + '/ButtonImage.png',
                        onclick : function() {  
                            ed.selection.setContent('[statistics_sp]');  
                                //var vidId = prompt("YouTube Video", "");
                                //ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '[youtube id="'+vidId+'"]');
                        }  
                    });


        }, 

        createControl   : function(n, cm) {     return null;  }, 
    });  
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('MyPuginButtonTag', tinymce.plugins.shortcodebuton_plugin2);  
})();
```

Comment: I think this not the best way. The include of the wp-load.php is not stable. The pace, where leave this file is different. The install of WordPress have default possibilities to move the theme and plugin folder.