# How to customize TinyMCE4 in WP 3.9 - the old way for styles and formats doesn't work anymore

Tags: tinymce

Before WP 3.9 i had the following two filters applied in the functions.php:

```
function my_mce_buttons_2( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'my_mce_buttons_2');

function mce_mod( $init ) {
    $init['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = 'p,h3,h4';
    $init['theme_advanced_styles'] = "Header gross=mus-bi news-single-bighead; Header klein=mus-bi news-single-smallhead; Link=news-single-link; List Items=news-single-list";
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_mod');
```

so that the paragraph formats dropdown only shows p, h3 and h4 while the custom styles dropdown shows "Header gross", "Header klein" and so on. But unfortunately wp and tinymce don't bother anymore since wp 3.9, i only see the standard paragraph formats dropdown now

[image: paragraph]

as well as the standard styles format dropdown:

[image: styles]

So far i haven't found any docs about if any hooks have changed with the update to tinymce 4. Anyone knows? Best regards Ralf

Update:
Ok based on a little more research and the comments beneath i guess i've figured things out:

```
//Creating the style selector stayed the same
function my_mce_buttons( $buttons ) {
   array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
   return $buttons;
}
add_filter('mce_buttons', 'my_mce_buttons');

function mce_mod( $init ) {
   //theme_advanced_blockformats seems deprecated - instead the hook from Helgas post did the trick
   $init['block_formats'] = "Paragraph=p; Heading 3=h3; Heading 4=h4";

   //$init['style_formats']  doesn't work - instead you have to use tinymce style selectors
   $style_formats = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Header 3',
        'classes' => 'mus-bi news-single-bighead'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Header 4',
        'classes' => 'mus-bi news-single-smallhead'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Link',
        'block' => 'a',
        'classes' => 'news-single-link',
        'wrapper' => true
    )
   );
   $init['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );
   return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_mod');
```

Comment: Have you seen http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139163/add-custom-tinymce-4-button-usable-since-wordpress-3-9-beta1?

Comment: No i haven't seen. Thanks! But unfortunately with the code described there it is only possible to create a button instead of reshaping style and paragraph drop downs. Have to keep on reading and researching.

Comment: Here's how you can keep the original menu items in `style_select` and add a "Classes" menu to it. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143689/tinymce-style-select-append-classes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look in `class-wp-editor.php` you'll find that the filter you are using is still there, however the settings are different.

```
self::$first_init = array(
                    'theme' => 'modern',
                    'skin' => 'lightgray',
                    'language' => self::$mce_locale,
                    'formats' => "{
                        alignleft: [
                            {selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: {textAlign:'left'}},
                            {selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'alignleft'}
                        ],
                        aligncenter: [
                            {selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: {textAlign:'center'}},
                            {selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'aligncenter'}
                        ],
                        alignright: [
                            {selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: {textAlign:'right'}},
                            {selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'alignright'}
                        ],
                        strikethrough: {inline: 'del'}
                    }",
                    'relative_urls' => false,
                    'remove_script_host' => false,
                    'convert_urls' => false,
                    'browser_spellcheck' => true,
                    'fix_list_elements' => true,
                    'entities' => '38,amp,60,lt,62,gt',
                    'entity_encoding' => 'raw',
                    'keep_styles' => false,
                    'paste_webkit_styles' => 'font-weight font-style color',

                    // Limit the preview styles in the menu/toolbar
                    'preview_styles' => 'font-family font-size font-weight font-style text-decoration text-transform',

                    'wpeditimage_disable_captions' => $no_captions,
                    'wpeditimage_html5_captions' => current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'caption' ),
                    'plugins' => implode( ',', $plugins ),
                );
```

I'm guessing, but I think you need to change the array key you are targeting to `formats`.

**EDIT** Leaving this in place, but the OP confirms that this does not do what he is attempting.

```
function mce_mod( $init ) {
        $init['formats'] = "{
                            alignleft: [
                                {selector: 'p,h3,h4,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: {textAlign:'left'}},
                                {selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'alignleft'}
                            ],
                            aligncenter: [
                                {selector: 'p,h3,h4,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: {textAlign:'center'}},
                                {selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'aligncenter'}
                            ],
                            alignright: [
                                {selector: 'p,h3,h4,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: {textAlign:'right'}},
                                {selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'alignright'}
                            ],
                            strikethrough: {inline: 'del'}
                        }";
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_mod');
```

Keep in mind that this is totally untested, so your mileage may vary. (And don't use on a production site until you've tested it).

**Continuing onwards**

Digging deeper the formats appear to be a custom tinyMCE button. You can see that the `formatselect` button is added to `mce_buttons_2` in the `class-wp-editor.php`. And then I tracked that to `tinymce.js` :

```
    editor.addButton('formatselect', function() {
        var items = [], blocks = createFormats(editor.settings.block_formats ||
            'Paragraph=p;' +
            'Address=address;' +
            'Pre=pre;' +
            'Heading 1=h1;' +
            'Heading 2=h2;' +
            'Heading 3=h3;' +
            'Heading 4=h4;' +
            'Heading 5=h5;' +
            'Heading 6=h6'
        );
```

With that in mind, I think the new target would be to 1. (ideally) change the `editor.settings.block_formats` or 2. remove that button by filtering `mce_buttons_2` and adding your own custom version.

**Tested and working**

```
function mce_mod( $init ) {
    $init['block_formats'] = 'Paragraph=p;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4';

    $style_formats = array (
        array( 'title' => 'Bold text', 'inline' => 'b' ),
        array( 'title' => 'Red text', 'inline' => 'span', 'styles' => array( 'color' => '#ff0000' ) ),
        array( 'title' => 'Red header', 'block' => 'h1', 'styles' => array( 'color' => '#ff0000' ) ),
        array( 'title' => 'Example 1', 'inline' => 'span', 'classes' => 'example1' ),
        array( 'title' => 'Example 2', 'inline' => 'span', 'classes' => 'example2' )
    );

    $init['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );

    $init['style_formats_merge'] = false;
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_mod');

function mce_add_buttons( $buttons ){
    array_splice( $buttons, 1, 0, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'mce_add_buttons' );
```

*Small caveat*: I'm not sure where to add the styles for the drop-down items themselves. In the TinyMCE sample, the "Red Headline" option is red. I couldn't figure this out. If you do please let me know.

Comment: thanks helga! i've looked into the class-wp-editor before too. But was unsure what the syntax had to be (there isn't much wp related documentation for the updated tinymceapi) . tried your suggestion now. same results like with my initial snippets. TinyMCE doesn't mind what the init looks like. on the tinymce site i've found an example for custom formats, js only, and i failed to adapt it towards wp and php: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php

Comment: ahhhh brilliant! the hint with  `editor.settings.block_formats` did the trick. I've post an update to my initial post. thanks!

Comment: Ah hah! You beat me to the solution.

Comment: Thank you all for making my life easier! The function stuff under heading "Testing And Working" worked for me. I also copied a bunch of my custom styles to the wp-content.css file found here:
wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/wordpress/wp-content.css And I can not only add special markup for my clients to use, but they can see what they've done!

Comment: Great help, thanks!  Just wanted to add that the `block_formats` option can't have a trailing ; .  I was building the value from saved configurable options and had a trailing ; that borked the list. Hope that saves somebody a few minutes.

Comment: @barback What!? Don't edit core files!! Add your own stylesheet via [`add_editor_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style)

Comment: Ah ha! Stumbled across you here too! I implemented the changes you mentioned in your blog, but hit the same issue a couple of people have mentioned, which is that the new TinyMCE4 doesn't seem to *add* inline-level elements when you add a class; i.e. selecting 'red' from "This red word will appear with in #CC0000", then choosing your custom `.red` format from the handy new **Formats** dropdown won't wrap 'red' in a span, but will instead add a class of `.red` to the *entire* surrounding `p`. Which is endlessly frustrating, and invalidates about half of my old functionality :/

Comment: @indextwo yup, I solved it here (as best as I could) and decided... hey... blog post! You don't get the class on a span even if you define it as inline? `array( 'title' => 'Red text', 'inline' => 'span', 'styles' => array( 'color' => '#ff0000' ) ),`?

Comment: @helgatheviking Oh holy crap you're right. I'd been going through the TinyMCE 'documentation' and concentrating on the `selectors` attribute, completely glossing over `inline`. Unfortunately I can't upvote this spectacular answer more than once, so here; have a comment upvote.

Comment: Sometimes you stare at things so long you can't see what's right there. Glad it worked.

Comment: The items in the format menu inherit the styles from your editor-styles.css, _except_ for the color styles. If you want the color styles as well, adding this code to the mce_mod() function worked for me: `unset($init['preview_styles']);`

Comment: @Dalton thanks for that. The [TinyMCE example](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php) has colors set in the options object. I assume there is a bug in WP's script or I've incorrectly decoded the options in PHP. The downside to making it filterable is that all the TinyMCE docs are in JS and we've got to send the options to WordPress via PHP.

Comment: @helgatheviking regarding your _small caveat_: you can enable all styles if you set `$init['preview_styles'] = 'font-family font-size font-weight font-style text-decoration text-transform color background-color border border-radius outline text-shadow';`. I guess this is essentially the same as @Dalton suggested, albeit in a more explicit way. This simply sets the default values, as per [tmce documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#preview_styles)