# Append Font Family in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to append font families to whatever prepopulated font formats are already in the dropdown. I could keep a [variable of defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14170758/800452) and append to that but I'm trying to make it as dynamic as possible should the defaults change in the future. All the tutorials I've seen thus far replace the defaults with whatever as seen below:

```
function tinymce_testerski( $init ) {
    $init['font_formats']   = 'Arial=arial,helvetica,san-serif';

    return $init;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinymce_testerski' );
```

The problem is that `font_formats` key doesn't exist in the `$init` array. I was hoping there would be a setting / option like [`style_formats_merge`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/143694/7355) but I couldn't find any such case in the TinyMCE docs.

I'm open to all solutions which would allow me to efficiently append font families to the "Font Family" dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `styleselect` key in the array of the TinyMCE settings for custom formats. This select is really useful for custom styles, enhancements. you find all relevant information for this solution in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128931/tinymce-adding-css-to-format-dropdown/128950#128950) to question #128931 in the same context.

## Via `fontselect`

But if you like to use the font select, then use the follow source as example. The result is, that the editor add a span-tag with the font settings in inline styles, like `<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Content</span>`.

The follow example source create this result, visible in the screenshot.
[image]

### Add Font Select

At first add the the key string to get the button to font select.

```
/**
 * Add the "font family" button.
 */
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'fb_mce_editor_buttons' );

function fb_mce_editor_buttons( $buttons ) {

    array_unshift( $buttons, 'fontselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
```

### Change Font List

Now you should see the default list of all fonts. The [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#font_formats) have also include the list of the default value, font list. To change this list use the follow example.

```
/**
 * Add fonts to the "Font Family" drop-down.
 */ 
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'fb_mce_before_init' );

function fb_mce_before_init( $settings ) {

    $font_formats = 'Andale Mono=andale mono,times;'
                  . 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif';
    $settings[ 'font_formats' ] = $font_formats;

    return $settings;

}
```

#### Default Fonts

`'Andale Mono=andale mono,times;'+ 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;'+ 'Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;'+ 'Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;'+ 'Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;'+ 'Courier New=courier new,courier;'+ 'Georgia=georgia,palatino;'+ 'Helvetica=helvetica;'+ 'Impact=impact,chicago;'+ 'Symbol=symbol;'+ 'Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;'+ 'Terminal=terminal,monaco;'+ 'Times New Roman=times new roman,times;'+ 'Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;'+ 'Verdana=verdana,geneva;'+ 'Webdings=webdings;'+ 'Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats'`

### TinyMCE 3 vs 4

Small hint, this works only since TinyMCE 4*, smaller this version you must use the key `theme_advanced_fonts` instead of `font_formats`.

### Use Google Fonts

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201296/google-fonts-and-tinymce) shoulds help.

Comment: I don't disagree but `styleselect` doesn't have a font list so I can't append any font - I would have to either have 2 separate selects: 1 with built-in fonts and the other ( in `styleselect` ) with custom fonts **or** I would need to recreate all the default fonts plus my custom fonts in a `styleselect` tab both of which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: But on default you can only use the standard items, no custom select. If you need custom selects, you should enhance the tinymce, much more complex. But you can see a solution in the plugin AddQuicktag.

Comment: The reason `styleselect` can't be used in this case is because it doesn't have a Fonts selection. I'm trying to get all the default fonts and append custom fonts.

Comment: Please check it with `fontselect` as key, instead to `styleselect`. I think this should get your the right select field for fonts.

Comment: Thanks for your help, `fontselect` is the correct button to add but I don't see a way to append fonts. If you could edit your answer with an example that would be super helpful!

Comment: Ok, now is it clearer for me and I can help you with a explain answer.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee If the answer is right, you should use the hook to present this. Also a vote as a small thank you was really fine :(

Comment: +1 for effort. It doesn't appear that what I'm asking is possible yet. As stated in the original question I'm trying to _append_ to the default fonts and I already know that I can *statically* keep a list of those default fonts but I'm trying to make it as dynamic as possible so I **dont** want to keep a static list of default fonts. There doesn't appear to be a hook or way to get any added fonts and just append to that though. Your answer appears to say to either 1) keep a variable of default fonts or 2) replace all the fonts entirely with your fonts, which is not what the question asks.

Comment: Maybe you add the items via javascript to this field. So it is possible to add it dynamically. Add this field, use his ID and add your custom list.