# TinyMCE Advanced Link Class List on the main editor

Tags: tinymce

I'm using the plugin TinyMCE Advanced and would like to achive a "link_class_list" to the editor when inserting a link. I tried a hundred things, but can't seem to get this work with the main (content) editor. I already set the TinyMCE Advanced link option to 'Other dialog to create/change links' on the settings page.  Maybe it's a wrong selector, I really have no clue..

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#content",
    plugins: "link",
    menubar: "insert",
    toolbar: "link",
    link_class_list: [
        [{title: 'None', value: ''},
        {title: 'Button (primary)', value: 'btn btn-primary'},
        {title: 'Button (secondary)', value: 'btn btn-secondary'},
        {title: 'Button (default)', value: 'btn btn-default'}]
    ]
});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to use the TinyMCE settings filter. Something like [one of my older questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/143689/7355)

Answer (score 0):

I understand the alternative, but I'm looking for a direct way to do this within the "Link dialog". See the image below.

[image]