# Customizing tinyMCE 4 Styles and Format dropdowns

Tags: tinymce

As has been pointed out in multiple posts here there are some big problems with tinyMCE 4 formatting for WP 3.9 - this code comes very close:

[TinyMCE: adding CSS to format dropdown](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128931/tinymce-adding-css-to-format-dropdown/145135#145135)

But there are problems - here are the ones that I have discovered:

- 'color' does not work (as I pointed out at the bottom of the question)
- 'block' =>'p' - does not work on its own, but it will if you add a class with 'classes'
- 'lineHeight' - does not work
- There seems to be no way to control the font size and type in the dropdowns

Has anyone been able to come up with a solution to any of these?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the font size and type in the format dropdown by [adding an editor style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style).

WPSE user [helgatheviking](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/6477/helgatheviking) explained how to add styles to the format dropdown in her post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141539/799). I've included the relevant code below with one minor adjustment which allows CSS attributes like color and line-height to be inherited by the dropdown items as well.

```
function mce_mod( $init ) {
    $init['block_formats'] = 'Paragraph=p;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4';

    //This allows color styles to be inherited from the editor styelsheet.
    unset($init['preview_styles']);

    $style_formats = array (
        array( 'title' => 'Bold text', 'inline' => 'b' ),
        array( 'title' => 'Red text', 'inline' => 'span', 'styles' => array( 'color' => '#ff0000' ) ),
        array( 'title' => 'Red header', 'block' => 'h1', 'styles' => array( 'color' => '#ff0000' ) ),
        array( 'title' => 'Example 1', 'inline' => 'span', 'classes' => 'example1' ),
        array( 'title' => 'Example 2', 'inline' => 'span', 'classes' => 'example2' )
    );

    $init['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );

    $init['style_formats_merge'] = false;
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_mod');

function mce_add_buttons( $buttons ){
    array_splice( $buttons, 1, 0, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'mce_add_buttons' );
```