# Snippet: Use classes instead of inline styles for text alignment

Tags: theme-development, tinymce, visual-editor, wysiwyg, html

WordPress' TinyMCE (WYSIWYG) editor is adding inline stlyes to the markup when you change the text alignment. This behaviour is hard coded in `wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php`.

Can the inline styles be changed to classes instead?

Comment: I appreciate your effort that you came up with something but this question, rather not-a-question is not suitable for this community. You should read this how to ask : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

**Note** This answer was originally included in [@bitstarr](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/111830/bitstarr)'s question above and was included as a separate answer here to comply with WPSE's Q&A model.

---

Maybe someone else will have this issue and so i will share my solution here with you folks.

```
function make_mce_awesome( $init ) {
    /*
        There are easier things than make 'left/center/right align text' to use classes instead of inline styles
     */

    // decode
    $formats = preg_replace( '/(\w+)\s{0,1}:/', '"\1":', str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), "", $init['formats'] ));
    $formats = json_decode( $formats, true );

    // set correct values
    $formats['alignleft'][0]['classes'] = 'text--left';
    $formats['aligncenter'][0]['classes'] = 'text--center';
    $formats['alignright'][0]['classes'] = 'text--right';

    // remove inline styles
    unset( $formats['alignleft'][0]['styles'] );
    unset( $formats['aligncenter'][0]['styles'] );
    unset( $formats['alignright'][0]['styles'] );

    // encode and replace
    $init['formats'] = json_encode( $formats );

    return $init;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'mkae_mce_awesome' );
```

First the settings have to be encoded to make them easy usable in PHP. Then we i add the class names (`text--XXX`) and remove the parts that cause the inline styling. At the end the array will be converted back.

**Bonus:** You can make the editor even more awesome by adding this line.

```
    $init['block_formats'] = 'Paragraph=p;Heading 2=h2;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4';
```

This will prevent users from using `<h1>` headlines - the SEO nightmare…

I hope this will be useful for somebody. Improvements are welcome!

Also see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141539

Answer (score 0):

good answer from cjbj but had to double encode it to get a nested array (instead of object) and access the classes/styles entry:

```
$formats = preg_replace( '/(\w+)\s{0,1}:/', '"\1":', str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), "", $init_array['formats'] ));
$formats = json_decode( $formats );

$formats = json_decode(json_encode($formats),true);

// set correct values
$formats['alignleft'][0]['classes'] = 'text-left';
$formats['aligncenter'][0]['classes'] = 'text-center';
$formats['alignright'][0]['classes'] = 'text-right';

// remove inline styles
unset( $formats['alignleft'][0]['styles'] );
unset( $formats['aligncenter'][0]['styles'] );
unset( $formats['alignright'][0]['styles'] );

// encode and replace
$init_array['formats'] = json_encode( $formats );
```