# Add custom TinyMCE 4 Button: Is it mandatory to have one JS per button?

Tags: tinymce

I'm editing a Wordpress Plugin, trying to add another button. I had a look to this question ([Add custom TinyMCE 4 Button, Usable since WordPress 3.9-beta1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139163/add-custom-tinymce-4-button-usable-since-wordpress-3-9-beta1/139164#139164)). But it doesn't work

The JS file: https://www.nonsolodiete.it/wp-content/plugins/perfect-pullquotes/perfect-pullquotes.js

The second button is not visible

[image]

The JS file (collapsed)

[image]

The impossible to debug JS error reported by Chrome..

[image]

What can I try?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the PHP file.

The Javascript file can contain two buttons but must be referenced twice as shown in the picture.

[image]